# Get access token for calling a protected WebApi from a WsFed Azure AD authenticated client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I have used the `OnSecurityTokenValidated` event for getting the token after authentication like so:

```
services
            .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxx";
                options.Wtrealm = "spn:xxxxxxx";
                options.Events.OnSecurityTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.ProtocolMessage.GetToken();
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("access-token", accessToken, new CookieOptions()
                    {
                        IsEssential = true
                    });
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "access-token";
            });
```

But, the token I get here is in xml format. It looks something like this:

```
<Assertion ID=\"_d45ddd2f-0417-413e-asdas-bf9417fcd400\" IssueInstant=\"2020-10-19T13:44:58.569Z\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"><Issuer>https://sts.windows.net/7ad4009f-sdfs-4576-81ba-3ad93dccbc9f/</Issuer><Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256\"/><Reference URI=\"#_d45ddd2f-0417-dsfr-a83e-bf9417fcd400\"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature\"/><Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#\"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256\"/><DigestValue>dA8KcNkKXnwBRR9AwTHBXvMZiwKC+hMEVL6U86Ct3Vk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>A1RikDWtXjlDiZixwzEEpzg9SZ52xgfJzcUq07FWGBenGFZYVZY7pa3RbfFWiI808+fVptKwIHDlndP+cn1MXuFr8jubK/aBvLK2XBtBQ7FYT0sxwZ8R5sYmPeJZL558P7JmPejAz9C5QnxUWuONiisQAbhFJofPpku4TpNK14BuYOc+Y7C1m8v5l/lgZUgmAY5/nVFl6H0f5FFApwjPg9AEQVN1+ZUkCU8yAAAFOyQF3AHMeLqYtBEINnf2vqDzEOWmDdwjrkJbBDfwWxD0uGiX6ZVbtcklG+G/JIbSDvHo/uHUtBrZaOpCswShrHwlDtyx8H6HrCA5440gn8O+fA==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature><Subject><NameID Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent\">knQ3jjiuyEK7fBlPy3wzD_jaJvUPxMI44mRt1oPoxbo</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer\"/></Subject><Conditions NotBefore=\"2020-10-19T13:39:58.444Z\" NotOnOrAfter=\"2020-10-19T14:44:58.444Z\"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>spn:66d4c072-8fa5-414d-af81-a9b15916a778</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid\"><AttributeValue>7ad4009f-0ead-4576-81ba-3ad93dccbc9f</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier\"><AttributeValue>8af7ecfe-ebec-4cb3-ad1a-8e973b3dd944</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name\"><AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname\"><AttributeValue>Vijayan</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname\"><AttributeValue>xxxxxxxxxxx</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname\"><AttributeValue>xxxxxxxx</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups\"><AttributeValue>23d3b69a-3b5d-4117-892a-32d1dfec6c63</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>7a874784-bb23-4051-b693-11807961551f</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>9c90fe93-8df7-48c9-82dd-b90db19c3544</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>2f4d75fb-179e-47ce-a388-3459aeabda2d</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>ad29d65c-76e3-4a27-bb4a-cb23014f532e</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>602f33ab-4561-4af7-9efb-c5b0ca10aa9f</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>27394d99-9cd4-4b0b-88d7-b2270b2608f4</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider\"><AttributeValue>https://sts.windows.net/7ad4009f-0ead-4576-81ba-3ad93dccbc9f/</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences\"><AttributeValue>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AttributeValue></Attribute><Attribute Name=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role\"><AttributeValue>Admin</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\"2020-10-19T05:31:13.432Z\"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion>
```

What I want is an access token so that I can append it to the headers in my HTTP Client and then call an API protected with JWT Bearer authentication. How can I do this?

Comment: WS-Federation protocol does not have any concept of client and access token - the only token being traded is the one sent to you for the web login, and there is no authorization code generated. We recommend you to switch to OpenId Connect.

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity In the docs, I have found a way to get the access token using the SAML assertion. Won't that work in this case? Doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion

Comment: ADFS with SAML and ADFS with WS-Fedration are two different concepts

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity We have a legacy system which uses Ws-Fed for federated login. So I am forced to use Ws-Fed. Is there anyway I can make this work?